# function vs method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In this example below is onlaod a function or a method? I would assume this is a method as that is associated with the img object.
Can anyone clarify this?

```
 img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);   
    ctx.drawImage(img, 170, 90);  
    ctx.drawImage(img, 170, 170); 
  };
```

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 4):

A "method" in JavaScript is just a property on an object that refers to a function. From [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-method):

> **method**
>
> function that is the value of a property

So in that sense, what you've shown is both a "method" and a "function."

In another sense, if you define "method" as "a function tied exclusively to a given object or class of objects," JavaScript doesn't really have methods at all (but keep reading). (More about that on my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html).)

For instance, you could consider `slice` a method of `Array` objects, but it can be used on any other object you like (as long as that object is *array-like*, since otherwise `slice` doesn't know what to do):

```js
var o = {
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    length: 3,
    slice: Array.prototype.slice
};
console.log(o.slice(1));
```

That said, some functions will fail with an error if they're called with `this` not referring to the kind of object they expect (for instance, [`Number#toString`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-number.prototype.tostring)), which in some sense makes them true methods.

In any case, it's very common indeed to use the term "method" to refer to a property that refers to a function. In fact, [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-method-definitions) does it when talking about things like this:

```
// ES2015+
let obj = {
    method() {
    }
};
```

and this:

```
// ES2015+
class Foo {
    method() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Methods are properties that are type Function**

Without formal language specific definition one should alway defer to the common usage implicit meaning.

**In computer programing;**

- A *method* is a function that is a part of a class, it may or may not return a value.
- A *function* is set of statements that returns a value.
- A *procedure* is a set of statements that do not return a value.

But if there is a language scoped formally explicitly defined meaning one should use it.

---

**Javascript's *function* and *method***

Javascript ["ECMAScript 6"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) formally defines the term *Function* as.

> ...and a *function* is a callable object.

and *Method* as

> A function that is associated with an object via a property is called a *method*.

Reference [ecma-262 7.0, Ecmascript Overview](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-overview)

*<sub>Which sucks as I have always used function and now have to emend all my documents to the correct term.</sub>*

---

**Contradiction**

It also creates contradiction in regard to the lexical syntax used to describe and document javascript code.

All callable functions/methods are `Function` objects and have the `Function.prototype`. In the strict sense there are only functions when describing what a variable is referencing (or anonymously).

For example consider

```
var poo = function(){}; // Method window.poo, function poo.
function Foo(){  // this is a function?
    var tic = function(){}; // tic is a function
    this.Bar = function(){ // this is a function as well as a method
        this.poo = poo; // This is a method, it is also function
    }
    this.Boo = function(){
        this.poo = function(){ return poo}; // anon function returns the poo
                                            // to create the method Boo.poo
    }
}
```

`Top` is a  function as it is a callable object. but it is also a property of the top scope `window` (or context top level scope), and is thus a method of `window`.

Thus as defined by the Javascript standard `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Boo` are *functions* and at the same time *methods*. This ambiguity in programing can be a problem that could lead to bugs, or worse design reviews if pedantic programmers like me are forced adhere to the design spec.

**Suggested lexical usage of "method" and "function"**

Personally I will opt to the following useage of the words *function*, and *method*.

- All callable statement lists are *functions*, that is their type.
- I will call them *functions* unless I referance the object they are a property of.
- I will call them a *method* when I referance without ambiguity the object they are a property of.
- If documenting with scope including JavaScript implementation language (usually c++) I will call internal (hidden from Javascript's context) callable code as *methods* or *functions* depending on if they return a value or not

From above code.

- `Foo`, `Bar`, `Boo`, and `poo` are *functions*
- `Foo` is a *method* of `window`.
- `Bar` is `Foo`'s *method*.
- `Bar`'s *method* `poo` does nothing
- `Boo.poo` is a method.
- `poo` is a *function*, that is its type.
- `poo` is a *function* common to both `window`, `Bar` and `Boo` *
- 'tic' is a *function*
- There is no *method* named `tic`.
- The *method* `Bar.poo` is declared in the *function* `Bar`
- The *method* `Bar.poo` is defined as an anonymous *function*
- The *method* `Bar.poo` is a referance to a *function*
- The *method*. `Boo.poo` is a referance to the *method* `window.poo`

*<sub>as there is ambiguity to the object that `poo` is a property of, refer to it as a function</sub>

The referance to the object that methods belong to can be a contextually explicitly reference.

- CanvasRenderingContext2D is an object used to render to the canvas , `drawImage` and `clearRect` are 2 of its methods.

Or contextually implicitly referred

- After getting the context from the canvas, the methods `drawImage` and `fillRect` can be used to overwrite all pixels.

Getters and setters are *functions*. They are methods of the object they are a property of but should only be called *functions* when referring to the declaration and defining statement list. Or as simply properties of the object. Calling them *methods* implies the function calling syntax `name()`

Anonymous *functions* can not be *methods* as they can not be accessed via a named property.

---

**To answer the OP**

- `onload` is a property of `Image`. It is never a function or a method of `Image`
- The object of type `Image` will have the *method* `onload` if defined, called when image has loaded. If the *method* `onload` is not defined then nothing will happen when the image has loaded.
- `img.onload` is a *method*. Or `onload` is a *method* of `img`. True only after it has been assigned a function
- `drawImage` is a *function*, that is its type.
- `ctx.drawImage` is a *method*.
- `drawImage` is `ctx`'s *method*,and it is a *method* of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

Comment: *"Without formal language specific definition"* Um...there *is* a formal definition of this for JavaScript. It's in the spec. I cited it in my answer yesterday: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-method: *"**method** - function that is the value of a property"*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes there is and did you read more than the first paragraph. I clearly referance and quote the same document.

Comment: I saw that you did that. So why open with a false -- or at least misleading -- statement? What's the point?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is neither false nor is it misleading.  It is relevant, if you are coding not just within the javascript environment. Most Javascript implementations are in C++ that uses the common convention and will need to use both common conventional and language defined meaning. It would be misleading to imply the meaning of function and method without mentioning the common convention. Nor do I believe that the ECMAScript defined meaning should or will remain in conflict. This answer specifically targets the inconsistency to increase awareness and that hopefully leads to change.

Comment: Okay, whatever, I don't see how the spec's definition and that sentence aren't in conflict, but frankly it's not important that I do. :-) Best,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I concur to the importance that a specific individual "see" a conflict. All that matters is that the message has been read.

Answer (score -1):

I would tend to say every function in Javascript is a method.  But I'm not sure if this is justified.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

So, a method has a "this", that is the object that was affected.

In your example this = img

```
img.onload = function () {
  console.log(this);
  ...
}
```

Well, any function has "window" as "this", unless it has something else as this.